# Libgdx serialization

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm trying to deserialize my game data on Android. I have the gamadata.dat file in my assets folder, however I keep having a `FileNotFoundException`.

```
FileHandle fl = Gdx.files.internal("gamedata.dat");
ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(fl.file()));

AllData data = (AllData) in.readObject();
in.close();
```

So why do I have this exception?

Regards

Comment: Do you use eclipse? Did you check the assets folder in eclipse to make sure it is there? Otherwise you might need to refresh the folder in eclipse.

Comment: Yes, I do use eclipse, it is in assets folder, however it's still not found

Comment: IMO this should work... Do you get the Exception on Android? Desktop? Both?

Comment: On desktop everything works. Only Android version fails.

Comment: In this case I'd suggest you to unpack the .apk file and make sure the file really got packed there as well.

Comment: I think I found the problem: http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/files/FileHandle.html#file%28%29

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [JavaDoc](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/files/FileHandle.html#file%28%29) it is stated that `FileHandle.file()` does not work with internal `FileHandles`.

Try this instead:

```
FileHandle fl = Gdx.files.internal("gamedata.dat");
ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fl.read());

AllData data = (AllData) in.readObject();
in.close();
```